# Abnormally high ssh traffic between remote linux computers

Tags: linux-networking, internet, bandwidth

### Overview

I work for a group that has several remote locations running multiple OpenSUSE Linux computers. These sites will generate and transfer data back to our local server, typically less than 1 GB per day.

Recently, we recently added Starlink as our internet provider, and since then there are periods where our data usage is incredibly high (up to 100 GB per day). We don't know what data is being transferred, and I'd like to fix it.

### Background

Our sites network setup is as follows:

- An FS dual-WAN gateway ([SG-3110](https://www.fs.com/products/115394.html)) balances two internet connections for each site: Starlink and a local internet provider
- All computers at site are connected to the gateway via a separate FS switch

This network setup is new, and was installed at the same time as Starlink.

### The Problem

Starlink shows very high data usage, with no obvious pattern. The severity varies with each site, from no usage at all up to 100 GB/day.

[Starlink data usage site 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSncD.png)

[Starlink data usage site 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e979v.png)

The problem started sometime after we installed the new network setup - the first occurrence varies by several weeks across all the sites.

I can monitor outgoing/incoming network traffic for all devices on the gateway, and I've noticed the abnormally high traffic on all computers at site (its not limited to a 1 or 2 devices).

### What I've done so far

To investigate this problem, I monitored the network traffic on a few problematic computers using wireshark and found the following:

- The traffic is exclusively betweeen our own devices - either between devices at the site, or from site to one of our local servers.
- Majority of the traffic was ssh packets from site to one specific local server. From one site computer, the packet rate was ~230 packets/second up and ~80 packets/second down, with an average data rate of 5 mbps for this specific server.

Next, I tried using `iftop` and `nethogs` on the local server receiving all the traffic in an attempt to figure out what was causing the unusual packets. I didn't manage to get any useful information from this however, besides seeing the data come into the server live.

### Next Steps

I would like to figure out what exactly is the source of the abnormal ssh packets between my sites and local server.

### Conclusion

Our sites mysteriously upload large amounts of data to our local server. The transfers happen randomly, in differing intensities across our sites, and I don't know why.

Does anybody have an idea as to what might be causing my problem? Or what further steps I can take to solve this problem? Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to be able to intercept and view the SSH traffic. Is this any use? https://www.ssh.com/academy/attack/man-in-the-middle

Comment: Maybe zeek could be help you further in your investigation. Zeek has a built-in SSH analyzer that can be enabled a configuration file

Comment: You could see the data transfers in nethogs and you couldn't derive any information from this?????? It tells you the pid handling the traffic from that you can get the session, identify open files, processes in the session group, the account being used.....what more were you expecting to find?

Comment: if you can see the sockets are open you can find what application software is sonnecting on them (I'm guessing rsync with no evidence at all)